# How can we show that these two are equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking at the exericse:

Let the finite group $G$ act transitively on the set $\Omega$. Then the action of $G$ and on $\Omega\times\Omega$ is defined as follows $(a,b)\cdot x=(a\cdot x, b\cdot x)$. 
Let $a\in \Omega$. 
Show that the number of orbits of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$ is equal to the number of orbits of $G_a$ on $\Omega$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

From the fact that the finite group $G$ acts transitively on the set $\Omega$, we have that there is just one orbit on $\Omega$.

We have that $aG=\{a\cdot g: g\in G\}$. This is an orbit of $a$.
Since there is just one orbit, we have that $Ga=\Omega$.

We have that $|G:G_a|=|aG| \Rightarrow \frac{|G|}{|G_a|}=|aG| \Rightarrow |G_a|=\frac{|G|}{|aG|}$

From Burnside's formula we have that the number of orbits of $G_a$ on $\Omega$ is equal to $$\frac{1}{|G_a|}\sum_{g\in G_a}X(g)=\frac{|Ga|}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G_a}X(g)=\frac{|\Omega|}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G_a}X(g)$$ 
where $X(g)=|\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \omega\cdot g=\omega\}|$.

From Burnside's formula we have that the number of orbits of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$ is equal to $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\tilde{X}(g)$$ where $\tilde{X}(g)=|\{(a,b) \in \Omega\times\Omega \mid (a,b)\cdot g=(a,b)\}|=|\{(a,b) \in \Omega\times\Omega \mid (a,b)\cdot g=(a,b)\}|=|\{(a,b) \in \Omega\times\Omega \mid (a\cdot g, b\cdot g)=(a,b)\}|=|\{(a,b) \in \Omega\times\Omega \mid a\cdot g=a \text{ and } b\cdot g=b\}|=|\{a\in \Omega \mid a\cdot g=a\}|\cdot |\{b \in \Omega \mid b\cdot g=b\}|=X(g)\cdot X(g)=X(g)^2$.

So, we have that the number of orbits of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$ is equal to $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}X(g)^2$ and the number of orbits of $G_a$ on $\Omega$ is $\frac{|\Omega|}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G_a}X(g)$.

How can we show that these two are equal?

Comment: It might be easier to argue directly. Since $G$ is transitive on $\Omega$, every orbit of $G$ on $\Omega^2$ contains elements of the form $(a,b)$. Then $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are in the same orbit of $G$ on $\Omega^2$ if and only if $b$ and $c$ are in the same orbit of $G_\alpha$ on $\Omega$. So the numbers of orbits are the same. (I think this is usually how the equality you are trying to prove is normally proved, so you may be trying to solve the problem in the wrong sirection!)

Comment: Why do we conclude from the fact that $G$ is transitive on $\Omega$ that every orbit of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$ contains elements of the form $(a,b)$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: We consider the orbit of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$, $(a,b)G=\{(a,b)\cdot g: g\in G\}=\{(a\cdot g, b\cdot g): g\in G\}, (a,b)\in \Omega\times\Omega$. 
We have that $(a,b)\in (a,b)G$. So that $(a,c)\in (a,b)G$ it must hold that $a=a\cdot g$ and $c=b\cdot g$, right? How exactly do we conclude that $b$ and $c$ must be in the same orbit $G_a$ of $\Omega$ ?

Comment: As you said yourself, there exists $g \in G$ with $a = a \cdot g$ and $c = b \cdot g$. That is completely equivalent to saying that $b$ and $c$ are in the same orbit of $G_a$ under $\Omega$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why we conclude from the fact that $G$ is transitive on $\Omega$ that every orbit of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$ contains elements of the form $(a,b)$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: I think you should be able to prove that yourself.

Comment: Since $G$ is transitive on $\Omega$ we have that there is just one orbit of $G$ on $\Omega$, right? How do we relate then the orbit of $G$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$ ? @DerekHolt